# Azure Servicebus connection PHP

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, amqp

I would like to connect with Azure Servicebus via PHP. The docs however from Microsoft itself are outdated and the libs mentioned and maintained by Microsoft are mostly abandoned.

If i am correct the Azure Servicebus follows the AMQP protocol? I am trying to connect via AMQP itself to the servicebus but no succes at all.

When i try to create a new connection with below an error is returned:

```php
<?php
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(
    '[[ REDACTED ]].servicebus.windows.net.',
    5671,
    '[[ REDACTED KEY NAME ]]',
    '[[ REDACTED KEY ]]'
);

/*
Fatal error: Uncaught PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPConnectionClosedException: Broken pipe or closed connection in /app/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:171
Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(157): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->read(7)
#1 /app/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(103): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->rawread(7)
#2 /app/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(586): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->read(7)
#3 /app/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(642): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_frame(3)
#4 /app/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(235): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_channel(0, 3)
#5 /app/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(352): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->next_frame(3)
#6 /app/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/Ab in /app/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 171
*/
?>
```

Hope someone can help me in the right direction

Best,
Pim

Comment: Here is some [Sample example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php) on how to connect to PHP Servicebus but as you mentioned in your question it will be retired soon but still if you use  .NetSDK to connect to Servicebus it will work.

Comment: Try connecting with .NetSDK as Microsoft itself clearly mentioned they will retire the application so you won't even get further resolutions if there is any issue in between

Comment: Im running a php app so what to do with a .net solution?

Comment: the above shared example is of service bus with PHP

Comment: Please be aware that your post leaked sensitive information, including your shared key.  I've redacted it, but it is still available as part of history.  Please consider the key compromised and roll it immediately.

Comment: @jesse thanks but is was already dummyfied so no worries!

Comment: @SaisaketgGuduru-MT but its a retired SDK? Seems that there is no proper solution anymore?

Comment: @Dirkos:  I can confirm that the Azure SDK for PHP has been retired and there is not currently an official SDK for PHP.    Service Bus is AMQP-based and it is possible to interact directly via AMQP.  However, the service contract is not formally documented, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-overview) is about as close as there is.   You may want to look into the [uAMQP wrapper for PHP](https://github.com/vsouz4/azure-uamqp-php/); it's not officially supported nor current, but it may help to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering this question on my own since i came to the conclusion that there is actually not a valid answer available. The SDK from Microsoft has been abandoned and there is no actual PHP solution for this at this moment of writing.

For me this means we will not consume the service but start using RabbitMQ instead.